# Can "fuzzy_transpositions" be set to "false" in a "multi_match" query in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, fuzzy-search

I've been searching but I'm not sure if "fuzzy_transpositions" can be disabled in "multi_match" query while using "fuzziness".

I'm getting a match for "cam" while searching for "games" using "fuzziness" as 1.

I tried to set "fuzzy_transpositions" as false but still gets matched. This is my code.

```
{
    function_score: {
        query: {
            bool: {
                must: [
                    [{
                        match: {
                            _id: 7676
                        }
                    }, {
                        term: {
                            store_codes: "de"
                        }
                    }], {
                        bool: {
                            should: [{
                                multi_match: {
                                    fields: ["frontname.*"],
                                    query: "games"
                                }
                            }, {
                                multi_match: {
                                    fields: ["frontname.*"],
                                    query: "games",
                                    fuzziness: "1",
                                    fuzzy_transpositions: false
                                }
                            }],
                            minimum_should_match: 1
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        functions: [{
            gauss: {
                rank: {
                    origin: 200,
                    scale: 100
                }
            }
        }],
        score_mode: "sum"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [fuzzy transposition](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html#query-dsl-match-query-fuzziness) has nothing to do with what you have. It doesn't apply in your scenario. As mentioned in the link, it solves a scenario where if your query is `ab` it would return *transposed* results i.e. `ba`.

I tried the scenario which you have mentioned and from what I understand, you might be using [Ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-ngram-tokenizer.html) or [Edge ngram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) tokenizer for your fields.

As mentioned in Edge Ngram link, let's say we have the below mapping:

```
PUT my_fuzzy_index
{  
   "mappings":{  
      "mydocs":{  
         "properties":{  
            "title":{  
               "type":"text",
               "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
            },
            "desc":{  
               "type":"text",
               "analyzer":"my_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "settings":{  
      "analysis":{  
         "analyzer":{  
            "my_analyzer":{  
               "tokenizer":"my_tokenizer"
            }
         },
         "tokenizer":{  
            "my_tokenizer":{  
               "type":"edge_ngram",
               "min_gram":2,
               "max_gram":5,
               "token_chars":[  
                  "letter",
                  "digit"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Let's execute the below **[Analyze](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html)** query now:

```
POST my_fuzzy_index/_analyze
{
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer", 
  "text": "games"
}
```

When you do that, you could see in the response the following tokens would be created. Which means your inverted index would have the below words.

`ga, gam, game, games`

Now if you search with what you have with `fuzziness: 1`, it would in fact apply the **same analyzer** at query time, which means it would also return results of above tokens and its fuzzy siblings having edit distance of 1 (`gam` and with edit distance of 1, it would also return `cam`).

What you could is, use `standard analyzer` in your search query as below, however note that fuzziness is still getting applied for e.g. it would return results with word `james` if your query is `games` as `fuzziness` is set to `1` but it will do away with searching for words lesser than **n-1** length of your query.

```
POST my_fuzzy_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "games",
      "fields": ["*"],
      "fuzziness": 1,
      "analyzer": "standard"            <---- this field here
    }
  }
}
```

*And if what you are looking for is to return similar results for e.g. like `game, games, gaming` then skip concept of fuzzy search and make use of concept of [Stemmer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-stemmer-tokenfilter.html).*

The entire point of using fuzziness is to show you certain unconventional results for e.g. manage misspellings, search based on usernames/product codes etc. So basically what you are observing is working correctly as per definition of fuzziness. This [link](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-fuzzy-search) should help you understand more on fuzziness.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for this clear explanation Kamal! I entirely missed this notification and I ended up putting this case in my backlog. I might need to tackle this out again and this is helpful!

Comment: @DanielDuque Not a problem and I'm happy to help!!